# Navigation menu taking up screen in mobile display/doesn't look the same as desktop

Tags: html, css, menu, blogger

When viewing my [website](https://www.latoyah.co.uk) on a mobile the top menu is all stacked up, and does not appear the same as the desktop version (a horizontal, single-line menu) Is there anything I can do to resolve this? My Knowledge is not the most advanced in this area.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a responsive design, one that adjust along with the resolution of whatever device is being used. This website I linked below is perfect to explain what you are looking for with the addition of examples.

You are looking for code that asks the device "what size am I?". The device will answer with the information, and then you can set parameters. "if device is 'mobile' Navigation bar should be 300px." This will also help if your user shrinks their web browser to half the screen or smaller, hence making it 'responsive'.

https://web.dev/responsive-web-design-basics/